# jQueryMobile / bootstrap / both

Tags: jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap

Today we got one version of the system for desktop and we got one version with jQueryMobile.
The goal is to only have one system/page for desktop, tablets and mobiles.

I know that bootstrap is a good css/js framework and it is responsive. That will soulve the todays problem with the desktop version of our system.

As I said we have one mobile version as well. But today it gives us some "double work". And it is made in webforms.

My thought was to use bootstrap for both desktop and mobile. But my boss like jQuerymobile look and functionality. 
We belive that our main users will be mobile/tablet users. So the best solution will perhaps be to remake the jquerymobile page and build it with MVC?

The *main* content of the system is for eployees to check their scheme, accept work-suggestions from their bosses and so on... This is in a calender.
There will be some more functionality in this calendar futher on.

Ofc there is some other stuff in the system but this calendar is the biggest.

My question is what direction we will go with this. The goal is to have one page/system for both mobile and desktop users.

Comment: My vote is for Bootstrap and it really works good and if you are good with css and js you can customize it in any way . Saves lot of time on writing basic functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JqueryMobile, I normally use another kind of windows events, but i have tried those events in normal pc browser and they tend to work okay. So why dont you build the system base on jquery mobile and just change the layout depending on who is making the request with a agent request.